# Webview dragging effect when scrolling

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I got `scrollviewer` that is using horizontal scrolling, at the end i put a `webview`. When I scroll from left to right the Webview has an ugly dragging effect (it moves a bit more and then goes back to its position) any way to disable that effect?

Though I have seen a particular [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/16518ff3-5ae5-4aab-a479-c3f6d69e80f0)  that claims to solve it with a `WebViewBrush` and did not explain how.

I would like to know how to use the WebViewBrush to stop the dragging effect.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first thing is that i wanted to get rid of the dragging effect the webview makes when scrolling the page, the approach i took was to use the scrollviewer's `EventArgs IsIntermediate` property that will be false when the user is not scrolling and true when the user is scrolling. From the result, i choose to make the webview's visible property to `Visible` if the user is not scrolling and to `Collapsed` when the user is scrolling. Here is the scrollviewer's `ViewChanged` event handler

```
private void ScrollViewer_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.IsIntermediate.Equals(false))
    {
         watchTrailerWebView.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
         Rect1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent);        
    }
    else if (e.IsIntermediate.Equals(true))
    {
         if (Rect1.Visibility == Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible)
         {
             WebViewBrush b = new WebViewBrush();
             b.SourceName = "watchTrailerView";
             b.Redraw();
             Rect1.Fill = b;
             watchTrailerWebView.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;                   
          }

     }            
 }
```

You could choose not to use the `WebViewBrush`, works fine by just making the `WebView` visible or collapsed